# clearcase remote rollback remove directory

Tags: version-control, clearcase, rollback, clearcase-remote-client

How can I rollback the operation of removing a directory and its contents in CCRC?

I have removed the directory and the changes are checked in on my view.
I can't run cleartool, the error I get is "You do not have a license to run ClearCase".
I have tried in eclipse CCRC plugin "Replace with another clearcase version", and specify the version I want, but nothing changes.

How can I get the directory and files back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cleartool` won't be available with CCRC. It is included only with a full ClearCase installation.

The way to restore a deleted element though should be the same : checkout the parent directory and merge its previous version (which still reference the sub-directory) with the checked out one: you will get back what was deleted (actually only de-referenced)

See also the [CCRC merge directory view](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_comp_merg_mrg_dir.htm).